# What are springboot dependencies needed for ElasticSearch 5.6.7?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Please share me the dependencies information about using ES 5.6.7 with springboot ?

As i have ES 2.4 and it is working now, but after upgrade failing to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.6</version>
</dependency>
```

You can check [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch) for further more dependency

Comment: I was asking for Springboot version, spring data elastic version etc ..